# Can I say " There do be something"?

Tags: do-support

We can say 'Do be careful', 'do be straightforward about it'.

And we can say ' There do exist...', such as:

----- From a synchronic point of view, there do exist cases of regular abrupt metathesis, ...

----- However, there do exist many situations where onsite capacity is the most viable option...

So I wonder if I can accordingly say sentences like'There **DID BE** such a teacher then in my school'?

Is it right(and why)? Have you ever seen such expressions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, it's not right.

Long answer: There DID not be such a sentence, then, in modern English.

Note that all your "Do be..." sentences are the [imperative "do"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood#English). That is, they're commands.

However, the "do" in "there do exist..." is there to [emphasize the contrast](http://www.grammaring.com/the-auxiliaries-do-and-does-for-emphasis) from previous sentences.

So, there **DID exist** such a sentence, then, in modern English, but there **did not be** such a sentence, then, in modern English.

Comment: Thank you very. So I finally get to know that the sentence THERE DID NOT BE SUCH A SENTENCE IN MODERN ENGLISH is right; and therefore THERE DO BE SUCH A SENTENCE IN MODERN ENGLISH is also right, is it? @Teacher KSHuang

Comment: I have not been able to add a comment here since I saw the answer. I can do it only from today.

Comment: @yhemusa Heh, no, both those sentences are wrong. Read the last sentence of my answer again: So, there DID exist such a sentence, then, in modern English (correct), but there did not be such a sentence, then, in modern English (incorrect).